# Proving that a convex cone doesn't contain the negative of any point in the cone

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Let $x_1, x_2 \in \Bbb R^d$ be two rays that define a ‘noisy’ convex cone
$$
C := \{ \lambda x_1 + (1 - \lambda) x_2 + \epsilon \mid \lambda \ge 0 \},
$$
for some vector $\epsilon \in \Bbb R^d$ with a small norm. Is it enough to assume that $x_1 \cdot x_2 < 0$ in order to say that $\forall p \in C, -p \notin C$?

I would appreciate it if you’ll have any references to support your answer.

Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d=1$, let $x_1=1$ and $x_2=-1$, $$\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2+\epsilon =\lambda -(1-\lambda)+\epsilon  = 2\lambda -1+\epsilon   \ge -1 +\epsilon $$

Hence if $0<\epsilon<1$, we have both $-1+\frac{1+\epsilon}2=\frac{\epsilon-1}2$ and $\frac{1-\epsilon}2 \in C$. To be even clearer, we can take $\epsilon = 0.5$, that is we have $-0.25$ and $0.25$ are both in $C$.

For $d>2$, to construct similar counter example, let $\epsilon = 0.25e_1$ where $e_1$ is the first unit basis, $x_1=e_1$ and $x_2=-e_1$. Then $\lambda e_1-(1-\lambda)e_1+0.25e_1=(2\lambda -0.75)e_1$ and we can repeat the same argument.

Remark: is the definition found in a book? Currently, it corresponds to a half line. I think it's more natural to define it by $C=\{\lambda_1 x_1 + \lambda_2x_2 + \epsilon |\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \ge 0\}$

Comment: Regarding your question about the source of the definition. We haven't taken it from any textbook. Possibly, it would be better if we would adopt your suggestion to define $C$ as
$$
C:=\{\lambda_1 x_1 + \lambda_2x_2 + \epsilon |\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \ge 0\}.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! My follow-up question is: What if we add the following assumptions?
$$
-1 < x_1 \cdot x_2 \le 0 \\
\| x_i \|_2 = 1 \\
S := C - B, := \{ ∣ ‖‖_2≤ \}
$$
As far as I see, to satisfy the required property $\forall p \in S, -p \notin S$, we must remove the ball of the small norm $B$, as defined in my comment above. That is letting $S := C - B$. Otherwise, starting from dimension 2, there is always a direction that a noise $\epsilon$ could disqualify $S$.

Comment: As far as I see, the combination of the two first conditions enforces the angle between the rays to be $\frac \pi 2 \le \theta < \pi$.


*NOTE: For clarification, in my last comment (in $B$'s definition), $ \in \Bbb R^d$.

Comment: If $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^d$, then the definiton of $B$ is strang. $\|p\|_2$ is a scalar and it is being compared to a vector.